# How to tackle these type of problems?

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, determinant

[image]

Hello all, I was having a hard time to understand these type of problems, I have tried something please check my solution and tell me whether there is a more appropriate method to solve them.

Ques. 23 I tried it taking a $3\times 3$ matrix and got the answer as $2$ and generalize it, so got $100$ as the answer.

I have no idea how to deal ques. 22

Answer (score 0):

Consider the matrix $A$ as a linear map on $\mathbb{R}^5$. Clearly, the matrix operates on a vector by permuting the elements of that vector in the same way as the permutation $\sigma$. The question we are being asked is: what power of $A$ gives the identity matrix?

Because of the equivalence of the matrix view and the permutation view, we can instead answer this question: how many times do we have to apply $\sigma$ to get the identity?

Looking at $\sigma$, we see it has a 3-cycle, taking 1 to 3 to 2 to 1 and so on, and a 2-cycle, taking 4 to 5 to 4 and so on. This means that applying the permutation 6 times will give the identity on both the 3-cycle and the 2-cycle, meaning that $\sigma^6$ is the identity permutation. Equivalently, $\sigma=\sigma^{-5}$, which means that $A=A^{-5}$.